# Python Fipy explicit terms with derivatives and variable diffusion constant

Tags: python, differential-equations, pde, fipy

I am trying to solve four coupled PDEs (two scalar density fields and one vector field- but I solve it component wise).
[image: Equations]

where the second term in first equation is given by
[image]

Now, in the Fipy code (the \rho and the vector components are denoted as by m, px and py respectively) I am writing them down as:

```
    mesh = PeriodicGrid2D(dx, dy, nx, ny)

    # Variables to use
    c = CellVariable(name='c', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    m = CellVariable(name='m', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    px = CellVariable(name='px', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    py = CellVariable(name='py', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)

    x_hat = [1.0, 0.0]
    y_hat = [0.0, 1.0]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    eq_c = (TransientTerm(var=c) == 
            W*(c.grad.dot(x_hat)*m.grad.dot(x_hat) + c.grad.dot(y_hat)*m.grad.dot(y_hat))
            - ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=x_hat * px*v0 + y_hat * py*v0, var=c)
            + DiffusionTerm(coeff=Da, var=c) + DiffusionTerm(coeff=W*c, var=m) )

    eq_m = (TransientTerm(var=m) == 
            kb*(c/(c+ch)) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=ku, var=m)
            - ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=x_hat * px*v0 + y_hat * py*v0, var=m)
            + DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dm, var=m) )

    eq_px = (TransientTerm(var=px) ==
            DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=px) - zeta0*c.grad.dot(x_hat) + zeta*m.grad.dot(x_hat)
            + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=((c/cs)-1 -((c/cs)+1)*(px*px+py*py)), var=px) )

    eq_py = (TransientTerm(var=py) ==
            DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=py) - zeta0*c.grad.dot(y_hat) + zeta*m.grad.dot(y_hat)
            + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=((c/cs)-1 -((c/cs)+1)*(px*px+py*py)), var=py) )


    # Couple them into one big equation
    eq = eq_c & eq_m & eq_px & eq_py
```

Is the Fipy implementation of the second term in c-equation correct? The code does not thow up any error but I am not getting expected results should be an aster as described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00149). But I get solutions that show aster initially but diffusion takes over and in long term I get homogeneous solutions. I have seen the previous related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494321/derivative-terms-in-fipy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552591/cellvariablediffusion-in-fipy), but not entirely sure how to make use of them. Thanks in advance and sorry for the poor figures!

Here is a minimal working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
First version with no polarity dynamics, no equation for n-field
"""

from fipy import (CellVariable, PeriodicGrid2D, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, ExplicitDiffusionTerm,
                  UniformNoiseVariable, Variable, FaceVariable, ImplicitSourceTerm, ExponentialConvectionTerm)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
import numpy as np


def run_sim(savename,K,zeta):

#------------ parameters -------------

    Da=1.0
    Dm=1.0
    W=-30.0
    kb=1.0/4.0
    ku=1.0/8.0
    ch=1.0/4.0
    cs=1.0/64.0
    zeta0=1.0
#    zeta=1.0
    v0=0.1

#-------------- Mesh --------------------

    duration=1
    dt=0.5
    # Define mesh size and number of points
    nx = 60
    ny = nx
    L = 20
    dx = L / nx
    dy = dx

    mesh = PeriodicGrid2D(dx, dy, nx, ny)

    xval = mesh.x
    yval = mesh.y

    # Variables to use
    c = CellVariable(name='c', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    m = CellVariable(name='m', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    px = CellVariable(name='px', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    py = CellVariable(name='py', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)

    # Initial condition + some random noise
    c.setValue( 0.1*np.exp(-0.25*(mesh.x-L/2)*(mesh.x-L/2)-0.25*(mesh.y-L/2)*(mesh.y-L/2)) )
    m.setValue( UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.4*(kb/ku), maximum=0.5*(kb/ku)) )
    px.setValue( UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.0, maximum=0.1) )
    py.setValue( UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.0, maximum=0.1) )


    x_hat = [1.0, 0.0]
    y_hat = [0.0, 1.0]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    eq_c = (TransientTerm(var=c) == 
            W*(c.grad.dot(x_hat)*m.grad.dot(x_hat) + c.grad.dot(y_hat)*m.grad.dot(y_hat))
            - ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=x_hat * px*v0 + y_hat * py*v0, var=c)
            + DiffusionTerm(coeff=Da, var=c) + DiffusionTerm(coeff=W*c, var=m) )

    eq_m = (TransientTerm(var=m) == 
            kb*(c/(c+ch)) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=ku, var=m)
            - ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=x_hat * px*v0 + y_hat * py*v0, var=m)
            + DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dm, var=m) )

    eq_px = (TransientTerm(var=px) ==
            DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=px) - zeta0*c.grad.dot(x_hat) + zeta*m.grad.dot(x_hat)
            + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=((c/cs)-1 -((c/cs)+1)*(px*px+py*py)), var=px) )

    eq_py = (TransientTerm(var=py) ==
            DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=py) - zeta0*c.grad.dot(y_hat) + zeta*m.grad.dot(y_hat)
            + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=((c/cs)-1 -((c/cs)+1)*(px*px+py*py)), var=py) )


    # Couple them into one big equation
    eq = eq_c & eq_m & eq_px & eq_py

    elapsed = 0.0   

    while elapsed < duration:

        c.updateOld()
        m.updateOld()
        px.updateOld()
        py.updateOld()

        elapsed += dt
        
        res = 1e5
        old_res = res * 2
        step = 0
        while res > 1e-5 and step < 15 and old_res / res > 1.01:            
            old_res = res
            res = eq.sweep(dt=dt)
            step += 1





        


if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    """
    comments
    """
    path = 'result/'
    

    def name(K, zeta):
        return 'K_{:.2f}_zeta_{:.2f}'.format(K, zeta)


    Ks = [1]
    zetas = [30.0]


    for K in Ks:
        for zeta in zetas:
            run_sim(name(K, zeta), K=K, zeta=zeta)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Fipy implementation of the second term in c-equation correct?

No. The term `DiffusionTerm(coeff=W*c, var=m)` represents [image: \nabla \cdot \left(W c \nabla \rho \right)]. There is no reason to run the chain rule to obtain the explicit parts; it is, in fact, undesirable to do so.

Further converting the orientation to a rank-1 `CellVariable` results in somewhat cleaner equations. FiPy cannot couple scalar `c` and `m` with vector `p`, but the `px` and `py` equations weren't coupled, anyway.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
First version with no polarity dynamics, no equation for n-field
"""

from fipy import (CellVariable, Grid2D, PeriodicGrid2D, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, ExplicitDiffusionTerm,
                  UniformNoiseVariable, Variable, FaceVariable, ImplicitSourceTerm, ExponentialConvectionTerm, Viewer)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
import numpy as np


def run_sim(savename,K,zeta):

#------------ parameters -------------

    Da=1.0
    Dm=1.0
    W=-30.0
    kb=1.0/4.0
    ku=1.0/8.0
    ch=1.0/4.0
    cs=1.0/64.0
    zeta0=1.0
#    zeta=1.0
    v0=0.1

#-------------- Mesh --------------------

    duration=1
    dt=0.05
    # Define mesh size and number of points
    nx = 60
    ny = nx
    L = 20
    dx = L / nx
    dy = dx

    mesh = Grid2D(dx, dy, nx, ny)

    xval = mesh.x
    yval = mesh.y

    # Variables to use
    c = CellVariable(name='c', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    m = CellVariable(name='m', mesh=mesh, hasOld=1)
    p = CellVariable(name='p', mesh=mesh, rank=1, hasOld=True)

    # Initial condition + some random noise
    c.setValue( 0.1*np.exp(-0.25*(mesh.x-L/2)*(mesh.x-L/2)-0.25*(mesh.y-L/2)*(mesh.y-L/2)) )
    m.setValue( UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.4*(kb/ku), maximum=0.5*(kb/ku)) )
    p[0] = UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.0, maximum=0.1)
    p[1] = UniformNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh, minimum=0.0, maximum=0.1)


    x_hat = [1.0, 0.0]
    y_hat = [0.0, 1.0]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    eq_c = (TransientTerm(var=c) == 
            - ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=p*v0, var=c)
            + DiffusionTerm(coeff=Da, var=c) + DiffusionTerm(coeff=W*c, var=m) )

    eq_m = (TransientTerm(var=m) == 
            ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=kb/(c+ch), var=c) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=ku, var=m)
            - ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=p*v0, var=m)
            + DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dm, var=m) )

    eq_p = (TransientTerm(var=p) ==
            DiffusionTerm(coeff=[[[K, 0],
                                  [0, K]]], var=p) - zeta0*c.grad + zeta*m.grad
            + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=((c/cs)-1 -((c/cs)+1)*p.mag**2), var=p) )


    # Couple them into one big equation
    eq = eq_c & eq_m

    elapsed = 0.0   
    
    viewer = Viewer(vars=c)
    viewer.plot()

    while elapsed < duration:

        c.updateOld()
        m.updateOld()
        p.updateOld()

        elapsed += dt
        
        res = 1e5
        old_res = res * 2
        step = 0
        while res > 1e-5 and step < 15 and old_res / res > 1.01:            
            old_res = res
            res = eq.sweep(dt=dt)
            eq_p.sweep(dt=dt)
            step += 1

        viewer.plot()




        


if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    """
    comments
    """
    path = 'result/'
    

    def name(K, zeta):
        return 'K_{:.2f}_zeta_{:.2f}'.format(K, zeta)


    Ks = [1]
    zetas = [30.0]


    for K in Ks:
        for zeta in zetas:
            run_sim(name(K, zeta), K=K, zeta=zeta)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the problem. I get confused while implementing derivative terms in Fipy.